# VBA issue between 2010 and 2016+

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2016, type-mismatch

We are having to use a legacy 2010 version of Excel to run some of our old macros. Can someone tell me what is wrong with this macro, that it runs fine in the 2010 version but not in the 2016 version? I am receiving a mismatch type error on the line in bold below. I'm guessing it's a change in Syntax but the $1700 Excel VBA course I just took still didn't answer my questions.  Thanks

```vb
Private Function GetDates() As Variant
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim lstDates() As Date
    
    strSQL = " SELECT DISTINCT(DATE) " & _
             " FROM [" & EXTRACTED_FILENAME & "$] "
    
    Call GetResultSet(rs, cn, strSQL)
    
    If (rs.RecordCount > 0) Then
        ReDim lstDates(rs.RecordCount - 1) ' <== Error here
        Do While (Not rs.EOF)
            lstDates(rs.AbsolutePosition - 1) = CDate(rs.Fields(0))
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    GetDates = lstDates
End Function
```

This is just one function as part of a very large extraction macro, but this is the first issue that halts the entire macro.

Comment: Are you sure it is the type mismatch error specifically, and on this exact line? What is the value of `rs.RecordCount`? Is your Excel 2016 64-bit? What is the exact version of ADODB that you are referencing? Why are you not using `rs.GetRows` instead of that loop?

Comment: Seems like if `If (rs.RecordCount > 0) Then` ran with no error then `ReDim lstDates(rs.RecordCount - 1)` should also succeed.